Logic App and Power Automate HTTP webhook expire time
I am unable to find details of Logic App HTTP webhook. What is the maximum time of waiting for a callback if no timeout is specified?
What is the maximum number of simultaneously running instances that can have an HTTP webhook waiting for a callback response?

For LogicApps, they're bound by the standard limits applied to max run time of any workflow.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption#run-duration-and-history-retention-limits
At present, you're looking at 90 days.
On consumption, they can't be adjusted to extend beyond the max but on standard, they can, that's part of the beauty of standard.
PowerAutomate is a little more restrictive ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#duration-limits
... you're looking at 30 days for any single flow.
Therefore, webhooks are bound by the overall limits but they're also bound by the limits you can set in the flow yourself.

